# r order factor levels in two nested columns

Tags: r, nested, levels

I have two columns with levels that are nested. By nested I mean that the factors in column 2 are dependent upon the values of column 1. I would like to order the factor levels in column 1 alphabetically. I would like the factor levels in column 2 to be alphabetically ordered after the alphabetical order of column 1.

```
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(c("A","B","D","C","A","B","D","C","A","B","C","D"),
                      c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Zeta","Chi","Omega",
                                  "Delta","Alpha","Gamma","Beta","Zeta")))

data<-data[with(data, order(factor(levels(data$V1))), 
                                      factor(levels(data$V2))), ]
```

I tried to order the factor levels as described above, but the second column is not ordered after the first; it is just alphabetically ordered on its own. I know I can manually type in the order of levels that I desire, but I am after something that doesn't require that.

Thank you.

Comment: They are already factors. So you should just order by their values.The order call should just be `order(V1,V2)` > The effect you are seeing comes from the fact that `levels(fac)` is generally a lot shorter than `fac` itself.

Comment: `data<-data[order(data$V1,data$V2), ]`

Comment: I should say that I would like the factor levels reorded for use during graphing using ggplot2. So far, none of these functions are preserved when I plot the new ordered data frame

Answer (score 0):

Like the following?

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(data, V1, V2)
   V1    V2
1   A Alpha
2   A Alpha
3   A  Zeta
4   B  Beta
5   B   Chi
6   B Gamma
7   C  Beta
8   C Delta
9   C Delta
10  D Gamma
11  D Omega
12  D  Zeta
```

Comment: I think you mean the library(plyr)

Comment: Note that this function will not preserve row names.

Answer (score 0):

`data<-data[order(data$V1,data$V2), ]` #should work

```
> data
   V1    V2
1   A Alpha
9   A Alpha
5   A  Zeta
2   B  Beta
6   B   Chi
10  B Gamma
11  C  Beta
4   C Delta
8   C Delta
3   D Gamma
7   D Omega
12  D  Zeta
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, or if the code is useful.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.